# Image doesn't show in browser

Tags: html

I'm adding a picture to the testing website i'm building, but it doesn't appear - instead it displays the `alt` text. What am I doing wrong? I'm using Adobe Brackets, and the image do show up if I hover over it in the editor.

[image]

```
<img src="detail.png" alt="main overview page of app">
```

Error message: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="header">App</h1>

    <img src="detail.png" alt="main overview page of app">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check the path or image name

Comment: Is the image `detail.png` in the same folder as your html file? If not, your path is wrong

Comment: @CodeLove I used autocomplete in Brackets to select it, it's in the same folder as index.html, and it does appear when I hover the mice over the path

Comment: @sailens it is in the same folder

Comment: Open the console of your browser using `F12`. Then try to reload and delete the browser cache using `Ctrl+R`. Is there any error?

Comment: Found an error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)"

Comment: Change the file permissions to (at least) read.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. I'm using OSX, and the file permissions denied everyone else besides myself to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your HTML code but in permissions to file. Probably the image has been created with higher privileges than you have when opening it.